# Haplodiploid species that are not eusocial

Tags: haplodiploid, eusociality

Haplodiploid species need not necessarily be eusocial and eusocial species need not be haplodiploid [(reference)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eusociality). Everywhere I look its been mentioned in general terms that some species of bees, termites and wasps are haplodiploid but not eusocial. What are some specific examples of haplodiploid species not being eusocial? I was specifically interested in bees but examples from other species are also welcomed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bee#Solitary_and_communal_bees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bee#Solitary_and_communal_bees)

Comment: @mgkrebbs That wikipedia page doesn't mention ploidy but the wikipedia pages for the species of bees do mention their ploidy. If you can write an answer, I can accept it and close the question. Maybe you could also mention a haplodiploid non-eusocial termite and wasp too in the answer.

Comment: feel free to post your own answer with that in it; that's allowed under site rules.